# How to set images inside of ImageView by URL Android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I found [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)"How to load an ImageView by URL in Android", which works fine for me, but in my case I don't want to just set a few images but a list of then, I have a Api RestFull which returns some strings and the Image URL, as I saw in that tutorial it uses a `AsyncTask` to download the image and set inside of `ImageView`, In my case I already using a `AsyncTask` to retrieve from my API, do I need to put something inside of my ModelClass to automatically download?

This is what I have...

```
public void getAdsUser(final Activity context){
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                Response = new WebBase().getUserAds(context);
                if(Response.equals("NODATA")){
                    return "NODATA";
                }
                if (Response.equals("EMPTY")){
                    return "EMPTY";
                }
                if (Response.isEmpty()){
                    return "ERROR";
                }
                else {
                    return "OK";
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "ERROR";
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            switch (s){
                case "NODATA":
                    GenericAlertDialog.MakeDialog(UserAds.this,R.string.NODATA);
                    break;
                case "ERROR":
                    GenericAlertDialog.MakeDialog(UserAds.this,R.string.Error_Internet);
                    break;
                case "EMPTY":
                    isVisible_ads.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case "OK":
                    UserModelView[] modelArray = new Gson().fromJson(Response,UserModelView[].class);
                    List<UserModelView> userModelView = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(modelArray));
                    adapterUserView.add(userModelView);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterUserView);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use Glide. - https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your life much easier and use Picasso.

loading images can be a simple one liner

`Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);`

See more on the site
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: I was half the way recommending the same thing.

Comment: Could you help me to use with my adapter?My adapter is a little bit different then a usual.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some complementary about why using Picasso is a better solution from what Stephen suggest. There are a lot of thing you need to consider like memory, caching etc. Picasso handle all of the hard work for you as long as you program it correctly and it is very simple easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Picasso library in your project and write code like this.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("image url").into("ImageView where you have to load image");
```